# validation message is not shown up with <b:selectOneMenu>

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I have following code to work with a `selectOneMenu` provided by `BootsFaces`. It works totally fine, except that the error message (validation failed) is not shown up. With a `<h:selectOneMenu>`, it also works. Also with a `<b:inputText`, perfectly. The error message is simple not displayed with `<b:selectOneMenu>`.

```
<b:messages id="nachrichten" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" />
<b:selectOneMenu value="#{userprofile.user.year}" required="true" requiredMessage="Pls enter year">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="year auswählen" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{yearHelper.allYears}" var="year" itemValue="#{year}" itemLabel="#{year.name}" />
    <f:facet name="append">
        <h:outputText value="" />
    </f:facet>
</b:selectOneMenu>
```

How can I fix, that the message is shown up while using `<b:selectOneMenu>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of a bug. Actually, you're using a feature we never promised. Funny thing is, I did implement some extra logic on when the `required` attribute is set to true. That's weird because I prefer the JSF303 bean validation style (and that, in turn, is the reason why I forgot to implement `required`).

I've opened a bug for you: https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/136.

Update 07/29/2015: As of BootsFaces 0.7.0++ (probably 0.8.0), the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Consider the bug solved as of BootsFaces 0.8.0. If you need the bug fix before September 2015 when we're probably going to release the new version, please tell me.

Comment: Well, actually I am doing a live-application with BF. Maybe, we can stay in contact, I found many other 'bugs' (and/or missing features) while working with BootsFaces. Well, the workaround is here to use divs with normal Bootstrap classes. It's working fine. If you wish, I can report those bugs.

Comment: Yes, please! I'm scanning StackOverflow.com every couple of days, but you get your bug fix a lot faster when you report the error directly on our page. Thanks!